How To Have Div Fixed To Middle Of Screen, Yet Only In The X-Plane?
So basically I want a div that is in the middle of screen and it is fixed there, but only in the x-axis, so no matter if I scroll left or right, it stays in the middle of the screen however when I want to scroll down I want to it to scroll away just like it would if it were relative. I hope you understand what I mean.
This is the code that I've put for that div so far when trying to achieve this.
#header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    width:200px;
    height:160px;
}

This code has it fixed in both the x-plane and y-plane, so that when I scroll down it stays in the same spot on the screen and it doesn't go away as I scroll down like it would if it were relative.
Update
This is all my code with the answer. Go into full screen snippet mode and then make your window small enough, so that you have to scroll for the image. And once you scroll enough the to the right, the header moves to the left.


.text{
    text-align:center;
}


#header {
    position: sticky;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    /* left: calc(50% - 100px); */
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }


#image{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height:600px;
    z-index:2;
    overflow:clip;
}


#div{
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background:linear-gradient(#1a1536,rgb(40, 9, 90), rgb(18, 29, 87),#1a1536);
    z-index:1;
    overflow:clip;
}
<div id="header">
        <h1 class="text">Title</h1>
        <h3 class="text">SubTitle</h3>
        <h2 class="text">SubTitle</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="div">
        <img class="place" id="image" src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconsdb.com%2Flight-gray-icons%2Fsquare-icon.html&psig=AOvVaw1fzZXNZn7_2YEF6WDUukgV&ust=1722012245418000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CA8QjRxqFwoTCPjMyNPRwocDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE">
    </div>




THank you for adding a runnable snippet, but I cannot see the image.

@AHaworth You're welcome. Like, is the black purple box with question mark not appearing? If the box is, then the example of my problem should still work.

You could use position sticky, with the left position as 50% but no top position set.
Here's a simple example:


<style>
  body {
    width: 300vw;
    height: 300vh;
  }
  
  #header {
    position: sticky;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    background: blue;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="header">fixed div</div>
</body>




You made a typo on 'top', it's currently working without the typo

Hi, it wasn’t a typo but a way of removing the top setting. I should have used CSS comment! Now removed as the important thing is that top should not be set.

yea mb, i missread OP's post. I deleted my post as yours match best his need

Your code goes work, however the margin-left is no longer working with the position:sticky; therefore it is not fully centered. You know how to fix that?

Apologies, I've edited the code to calculate the left position now, and made the element have a colored background so you can see it is centered.

That worked! Thank you very much!

Aight, so basically what you have isn't working all the way, 'cause when I make the screen small enough and scroll to the right, the header div just goes to the left and doesn't stay in the middle. So, how do I fix that?

Have you tried tranform translate?

@AHaworth I just tried that and it still does the same thing. I'm new to this. So to not make the mistake I made last time, what should I do so that you all can see more of my code, so that you have more context to help me?

I don't understand why that didn't work. It works in the snippet which I've just edited to get the element shifted by half its width using a translate rather than a -100px.

@AHaworth I'm pretty sure I now why yours is working. Yours scrolls because of viewport width, however mine begins when an image becomes too big for the screen, then the scrollbar appears. So, in your snippet instead of using viewport width, use an image to cause the scrollbar to appear. Then see if that works, because that is the situation I'm in.

Can you add relevant code to your question - I can't guess what the code is that causes the scrolling! Make a runnable snippet that defiitely shows the problem.
